# For loop - more in output than needed

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

Well all I had to do was:

- user has to enter 20 numbers.
- and I should find from array numbers lower than the last number user entered ( 20 numbers )

Example :

User enters:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,4
```

Output should be:

```
1,2,3
```

according to me, my output is correct. But after 1,2,3 alot of 0 come in.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int i,skaitlis,sk2,x;
int masivs[19];
int main() {


for ( i=0; i<=19; i++ )
{
   cin >> masivs[i];
   skaitlis = masivs[19];
}

for (i=0;i < sizeof masivs; i++){
    if ( masivs[i]<skaitlis){
        cout << masivs[i] <<endl;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `ì<=19` means you access the element 19, which is outside your array: undefined behaviour.

Comment: Compile with [all warnings switched on](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfa4445a11db2744). The compiler already tells you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for (i=0;i < sizeof masivs; i++){
```

The `sizeof` operator returns the size of the array *in bytes*, not in number of elements. On normal modern systems the size of an `int` is four bytes, meaning `sizeof masivs` will give you `4*19`.

That will lead the loop going massively out of bounds and give you *undefined behavior*.

Not to mention the *other* out of bounds you have in the previous loop.

Also, taking about the first loop, why have the assignment to `skaitlis` inside the loop? After you fix the out-of-bounds indexing, it will just assign zero (because `masivs` is a global variable and therefore initialized to all zeroes) except in the last iteration. You can move that assignment to be outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed out of bound loops, and removed skaitlis inside the loop and everything works now.
thanks! :)